# Can't install gattlib on Raspberry Pi: error: stray ‘\xxx’ in program on usr/include/boost/... hpp files

Tags: c++, boost, bluetooth, raspbian, pybluez

I read all the other Q&A about the stray error, but I couldn't find anything similar to my issue...

So:
I need to add BLE support to [pybluez](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez) on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (running on [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) [Jessie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) Lite kernel v.4.4) and, when it comes to build gattlib, I got a huge list of these errors (here's an extended copy-paste of console output: https://pastebin.com/KjRB5rB7):

```
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp:5:1: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp:5:1: error: stray ‘\264’ in program
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp:5:1: error: stray ‘\334’ in program
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp:5:1: error: stray ‘\354’ in program
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp:5:1: error: stray ‘\377’ in program
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp:5:1: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
```

I know it's a problem of character encoding, but it looks very strange to me that this happens on downloaded code.

Is there a way to fix this and proceed with installation?

I'm connected in SSH through a MacBook Pro running on [Mac OS X v10.10.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) and the charset of the hpp file is binary.

Answer (score 8):

#### Install gattlib on Raspberry Pi

I have had some difficulty in determining that gattlib was missing and then more difficulty getting it installed.

The project relates to installing a [Bluetooth low energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) (BLE) thingy on a Raspberry Pi using Python.

```
from gattlib import *
```

gives

> ... ImportError:  No module named gattlib

Or finding *ble* in Bluetooth, since *ble* is a simple wrapper for gattlib.

gattlib should be in the */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory*, along with Bluetooth thingy.

There are some dependencies you need to install first.

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev bluez bluez-hcidump  libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev libglib2.0-dev

​sudo pip install gattlib
```

It failed in my case, because there was only 100 MB in the swapfile. Mine worked when I made it 800, but it failed at 500. In my (limited) experience, a failure will occur with an error message. The compiling and so on takes a *very* long time.​

```
sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

​It's easy to see what needs to be changed here! Then stop and start it.​

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start

sudo free -m
```

​This last one shows you how much free space you have.

```
​sudo pip install gattlib
```

eventually (15? minutes later), it finishes.

Comment: This solution worked for me on a Raspberry Pi Zero. It took longer than 15 minutes, but it is a Zero.

Comment: This solution worked for me on a Raspberry Pi 3 64 bit running Raspian with Python 3

Answer (score 1):

I solved it simply by giving up trying to install pybluez and installed *bluepy* instead.

Comment: They are not the same and rarely updated.